# Performance difference between VARCHAR2 to NUMBER

Tags: sql, database, performance, oracle

If I query my DataBase (Oracle) with unique Index on multiple columns, Will there be any performance difference if I change one of the columns from VARCHAR2 to NUMBER?
If there is, is it **significant**?

(It's varchar2 because I need '0' at the beginning but I can change it in the presentation layer in my app)

Comment: you need to define 'significant'.  NUMBERS will be faster.

Comment: The difference between VARCHAR2 and NUMBER is not so significant (they are stored similarly). The ORDER of columns in multi-column unique index might matter a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

More knowledgeable people than me tell me that in Oracle the performance difference between number and varchar2 depends entirely on your data, since internally they have very similar representations.
See the following:

https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:2669498700346402356

but also look at the "Internal Numeric Format" section of:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#CNCPT012

If, for example, your varchar data was actually single characters (such as 'Y', 'N') then you'd probably be better off with varchars than numerics.  If you've got fewer than 100 codes but your string equivalents were 8 characters long then you'd probably be better off with numerics than varchars.

Comment: Thank you, though late to the party, the link to Tom was worth it... :)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it should be quicker to use NUMBER. Whether it gives you a *significant* increase will depend on your data, indexes and queries. If you're having performance problems, this is unlikely to be the magic fix.

Comment: Is there a measure to know how much influence there will be? let's say in percents.  I don't have performance problems, but I don't want to have some day..

Comment: And if that column won't be one of the unique index and I won't filter by him, only get his value, will it still decrease the performance?

Comment: @gdoron You're almost always better off storing numbers as numbers and text as text. Using the NUMBER type should be more efficient (in terms of both space and performance), and you side-step some potential problems (e.g. early warning if you accidentally try to store something that isn't a number in that column). If you've only got a small amount of data, you probably won't notice much difference in performance by making this change, but if it's cheap to do and test then it's probably the right thing to do.